# Search Data in mysql table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 78871 records in one table(mysql).can we search particular data in table..if any one knows please help me.

```
like ctrl+shift+f
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE "%search_text%";
```

This is what you are looking for. If you give us more context, we can answer more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just query it?

```
SELECT * FROM your-table
WHERE your-column LIKE '%your-criteria-here%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Database, select "SQL" in the top menu and write a Simple SELECT statement like that: 
SELECT * FROM (your database's name) WHERE (column name ) = (specific value)

It is possible to search for more than one logical criteria by adding 
conditions with AND or OR.

Also you could search more advanced with LIKE :
[cheap w3school example(s)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Very Basic sql knowledge by the way

Comment: i know about query but i have only value . i don't know about column name and there are many fields .

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

depending on the names of your tables in your database.

you would need to run a command similar to this example here-

```
Select * from person where p.personname = 'John'
```